# Hover image and show it next to the cursor

Tags: jquery

I would like to know if there is a way to show the same image as you are hovering, with a different size, next to the cursor? And on mouseout, it should disappear.

Comment: Yes there's a way. It's not really hard either. What have you tried so far? So you have any markup already? Or were you just planning to ask if it was possible, cause it is.

Comment: Hope the community will not be angry with me, for answering this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this will work. Adjust to your needs. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/jF27b/

```
var $img = $('img');
$img.hide();
$('div').mousemove(function(e) {
    $img.stop(1, 1).fadeIn();
    $('img').offset({
        top: e.pageY - $img.outerHeight(),
        left: e.pageX - $img.outerWidth()
    });
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $img.fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Change `mouseout` to `mouseleave` to get rid of mild flickering if hovering over the image (moving cursor up and left)

Comment: Yes, `mouseout` is fired when the mouse is out of the element, which at the time of hovering over `img`, it is out of `div`. `mouseleave` on the other hand is when the mouse leaves the element and takes child elements into consideration. So since `img` is inside of `div` the event isn't fired.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way you can do it.

Markup Structure

```
<li class="thumb">
    <img class="small" src="http://stackoverflow.com/" />
    <img class="large" src="someimage.jpg" />
</li>
```

jQuery Snippet

```
$(".thumb").mouseover(function() {    
   $(this).children(".large").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
   $(this).children(".large").hide();
});
```

<sup>P.S: <strike>I am not going to test this code to work, because</strike> I completely agree with @OptimusCrime</sup>

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TG76q/)

Comment: I have to be honest, it's noble that you promote that cause, but it's better not to provide an answer than to provide one that's untested and potentially worthless.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/BaDCe/