# jQuery image hover/float next to cursor when hover over any "a" link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, hover

Hi i have this code sample from [This Post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478796/hover-image-and-show-it-next-to-the-cursor) What i want is a png image to display next to the cursor when the cursor goes over a hyperlink or any kind of "a" link.

Here's the original:

```
var $img = $('img');
$img.hide();
$('div').mousemove(function(e) {
  $img.stop(1, 1).fadeIn();
  $('img').offset({
    top: e.pageY - $img.outerHeight(),
    left: e.pageX - $img.outerWidth()
});
}).mouseleave(function() {
$img.fadeOut();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<img src="http://i574.photobucket.com/albums/ss184/wsganewsletter/Other/Icon-Mega.png"    
/>
</div>
```

and here's the version i tried to modify without using HTML and loading the image only through jQuery :S

```
*var img = $("../Cursor.png");
$img.hide();
$('a').mousemove(function(e) {
  $img.stop(1, 1).fadeIn();
  $('img').offset({
    top: e.pageY - $img.outerHeight(),
    left: e.pageX - ($img.outerWidth()/2)
});
}).mouseleave(function() {
$img.fadeOut();
});?
```

I'm sure it's a relatively easy fix and i'm still leaning, could you please help me.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what you are needing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $img = $("#cursor");
        $img.hide();
        $('a').mousemove(function(e) {
            $img.stop(1, 1).fadeIn();
            $img.offset({
                top: e.pageY - $img.outerHeight(),
                left: e.pageX - ($img.outerWidth()/2)
            });
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            $img.fadeOut();
        });
    });
</script>

<img id="cursor" src="http://i574.photobucket.com/albums/ss184/wsganewsletter/Other/Icon-Mega.png" style="position: absolute">
<a href="#">hover me</a>
```

Comment: Hey thanks that's great!
it's just when you move the cursor around the link/text the image can be a bit picky and disappears easily when you go between the transparent pixels of text.
Is there some way to have an invisible region or div over the text with a bit of padding?
Thanks

Comment: @happycamper1221 and future visitors the flickering issue is from momentary mouse hovers over the hovered image, causing it to disappear only for the mouse to then hover the anchor tag and redisplay the image in a new location.  I fixed it by just adding a small offset to the top and left.  Here is my fiddle solution: http://jsfiddle.net/pTt5w/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a img tag like this:

```
var img = $('<img src="../Cursor.png"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to construct the DOM element - something like:

```
var img = $("<img id='myimg' src='../Cursor.png' />");
```

Comment: Hi i can't get Tahir Yasin's or your code sample to work, been trying for the last hour :(
could you edit your sample to work with the whole script- Thanks

Comment: It needs to have no HTML for what i'm constructing.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize you replied... the image just isn't showing with this code when i hover over but it does with the HTML @Tahir Yasin response. 

But i can't use HTML?